# Show Inf in DT::datatable()

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

I would like to explicitly show the `Inf` value inside a *datatable* instead of a blank

```
iris[1, 1] <- Inf
DT::datatable(iris[1:2, ])
```

[image]

I don't want to turn the column info character to be able to sort the column (If I do this, sorting will be alphabetically)

Any ideas?

---

**Edit:**

I thinks it's possible to adapt this kind of code :

```
datatable(iris[c(1:20), ], options = list(columnDefs = list(list(
  targets = 5,
  render = JS(
    "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
    "return type === 'display' && data.length > 2 ?",
    "'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' + data.substr(0, 2) + '...</span>' : data;",
    "}")
))))
```

with @MLavoie solution, it doesn't distinct `NA` and `Inf`

```
df = iris
df[1,1]<-Inf
df[2,1]<-NA
DT::datatable(df)
library(DT)
DT::datatable(df[,], options = list(columnDefs = list(list(
  targets = 1,
  render = JS(
    "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
    "return data === null ? 'Inf' : data;",
    "}")
))))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is :

```
options(htmlwidgets.TOJSON_ARGS = list(na = 'string'))

iris[1,1] <- NA
iris[2,1] <- Inf
DT::datatable(head(iris))
```

thanks to @yihui-xie and @Jeroen at : https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/496#issuecomment-363867449

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
df = iris
df[1,1]<-Inf
datatable(df[1:2,], options = list(columnDefs = list(list(
    targets = 1,
    render = JS(
        "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
        "return data === null ? 'Inf' : data;",
        "}")
))))
```

and you could also do it manually:

```
DT::datatable(df[1:2,], editable = TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks, but in this case it doesnt distinct Inf and NA (see my edit )

Comment: you could maybe replace the NA by a numeric values **df[is.na(df)] <- '-999'** and then something like **"return data === '-999' ? 'NA' : data;",** but I don't know how to make them both (with **"return data === null ? 'Inf' : data;",**) work together.