# Insert NAN as a numericInput in DT::datatable in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, numeric-input

I need to put a NAN value in my table's cell, whose type is numeric. whenever I try to insert a Blank into a cell, the application converts it to a Zero number.
My question is how can I provide my users with the ability of inserting NaN/NA value in shiny UI?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
 server <- function(input,output){
   rv <- reactiveValues(
     data = data.frame(iris)[c(1:10),]
   )
   
   output$table1 <- renderDT(
     datatable(rv$data, editable = TRUE
     )
   )
 }
 shinyApp(ui = DTOutput("table1"), server = server)
```

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48592842/show-inf-in-dtdatatable

Comment: The zero is a bug, it is fixed in the development version.